# Python Pass function parameter as list identifier

Tags: python, list, function, substitution

I've created a function which can take a parameter which defines another call to manipulate a list.  For example if I call sliprotor(Rotorid1, 1) directly, then the Rotorid1 list is manipulated as I want.  Function below:

```
def sliprotor(rotorid,offset_qty):                          
    for movers in range(26,0,-1):
         rotorid[movers-1+offset_qty]=rotorid[movers-1]     
    for movers_refill in range(offset_qty):
         rotorid[movers_refill]=rotorid[movers_refill+26]
```

However, if I try to call this 'indirectly' by building the list name and then executing it, 'rotorid' is not translated to the value, as it is when called directly.

The way I am doing this is

```
def set_curr_rotor(XX): 
    rotorid = "Rotorid"+str(XX)             
    return rotorid  

rid1 = input("First rotor slip : ")         
if(rid1): 
    sliprotor(set_curr_rotor(rid1),1)
```

So the 'indirect' call doesn't pass the value created by the set_curr_rotor function into the sliprotor function.  The direct call does use the passed in value.

If I look in debug, you can see that it is directly calling rotorid[] as the list, not Rotorid1 or other Rotoridx and hence I get an index error.

....
  File "", line 3, in sliprotor
    rotorid[movers-1+offset_qty]=rotorid[movers-1]
IndexError: string index out of range

I could restructure the way I have the code, but I would prefer not to.  Is there some method / scope issue I am missing?  Is this just an intrinsic attribute of Python?  I'm very new to Python so I'm just doing an exercise to model an Enigma machine.

Any help appreciated.
Ed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Don't do this. It is poor design. Use a *container* instead.

Comment: Fundamentally, *don't mix up your string objects with variable names*. You can use all sorts of sorcery to do this, but again, it's very, very bad practice.

Comment: Keep your lists in a dictionary.  Then you can cunstruct keys as strings to access the lists in the dictionary.

Comment: I'll look at using a dictionary of lists.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you have defined your rotors already, something like this:

```
Rotorid1 = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
Rotorid2 = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

And now you're reluctant to change this, because ... reasons.

That's fine. But you're still wrong. What you need to do is to create a larger data structure. You can do it like this:

```
Rotors = [ Rotorid1, Rotorid2, ... ]
```

Now you have a list-of-lists. The `Rotors` variable now *contains* all the various `Rotorid` variables. (Well, it references them. But that'll do.)

Instead of passing in the variable name as a handle to the rotor, you can simply pass in an index number:

```
def set_rotor(id):
    global Current_rotor
    Current_rotor = id

def slip_rotor(amount):
    global Current_rotor
    global Rotors

    rotor = Rotors[Current_rotor]

    for movers in range(26,0,-1):
        rotor[movers-1+offset_qty]=rotor[movers-1]      
    # etc...
```

Also, be sure an look up [slicings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) in Python - you can do a lot by manipulating sublists and substrings using slices.

Comment: If he is having problems with the dictionary index (or list) , I think that it would be useful to check if the element exist in the list (or the key exists in the dict)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  Actually my rotors are lists of lists, but I have no philosophical objection to changing them.  I'll be doing that.  It really was just a question to confirm that what I was attempting was not supported, and it's not, so I'll look at alternatives.

Comment: OK, so I think my basic assumptions about what you can or cant do within python lists of lists are wrong.  You cant seem to retrieve a name held within one list as a reference for another list.  i.e. if I have top_list = [l1,l2,l3]  and l1=[[i11,i12,i13],[i21,i22,i23],[i31,i32,i33]], l2=[[m11,m12,m13],[m21,m22,m23],[m31,m32,m33]], l3= [[o11,o12,o13],[o21,o22,o23],[o31,o32,o33]] and I refer to top_list[0] I cannot use that as a reference to l1 which allows me to access the lists within it.

Comment: You can, if you are storing references. You don't want to be storing literal strings.

Comment: I'll create a 3 deep list of lists.